# JSON to a new GeoJSON

Tags: json, geojson

I am trying to create a new GeoJSON from a JSON but I am having difficulties, because when I create the file, only one marker of each track is identified, but even then the coordinates are not loaded in the new GeoJSON.

```
            $.getJSON("test.json", function (jsonData) {
            var geojson = {
                type: "FeatureCollection",
                features: [],
            };


            for (i = 0; i < jsonData[0].track.length; i++)
                geojson.features.push({
                    "type": "Feature",
                    "geometry": {
                        "type": "Point",
                        "coordinates": [parseFloat(jsonData[0].track[i].coordinates.long),
                                        parseFloat(jsonData[0].track[i].coordinates.lat)]
                    },
                    "properties": {
                        "start": jsonData[0].track[i].start,
                        "end": jsonData[0].track[i].end
                    }
                });

            console.log(geojson)
        });
```

The JSON file that I'm using.

```
[{
"track": [{
    "start": "02/03/2020-07:10",
    "end": "02/03/2020-12:30",
    "coordinates": [{
        "lat": "-22,902262",
        "long": "-47,229826",
        "time": "02/03/2020-07:12"
    }, {
        "lat": "-22,901539",
        "long": "-47,24134",
        "time": "02/03/2020-12:30"
    }]
}, {
    "start": "14/02/2020-18:45",
    "coordinates": [{
        "lat": "-22,855182",
        "long": "-47,225476",
        "time": "02/03/2020-18:46"
    },{
        "lat": "-22,873228",
        "long": "-47,227868",
        "time": "02/03/2020-18:52"
    }]
}]   }]
```